# In which scenario would EndSend receive a SocketException?

Tags: c#, sockets, socketexception

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f6fk8ze%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *Socket.EndSend* method can throw a *SocketException* for a socket using connection-orientated protocol. When ?

I tested a couple of scenarios and none threw a *SocketException*.

Scenario 1: App calls *BeginSend*, and while it's sending the data, the app calls *BeginDisconnect/Disconnect*
Result: Socket doesn't send FIN until all data is sent, and *EndSend* is successful.

Scenario 2: App calls *BeginSend*, and while it's sending the data, the socket receives a RST from the remote endpoint.
Result: Socket stops sending data, calls the Callback and *EndSend* is successful reporting that all bytes have been sent. Don't understand why ?

When does *Socket.EndSend* method throw a *SocketException* on a connection-orientated protocol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it does raise an error if the connection was severed (as opposed to orderly shut down). You should be able to reproduce this behavior by pulling the network cable. If you can't, please post some code.

Comment: I disabled the NIC used by a socket that was sending data, and on calling *EndSend* it threw a *SocketException*